# Jquery animation will not run locally - Works in JSfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm fairly new to Javascript and Jquery but I can't figure out for the life of me why my code will not run properly locally. I've tested it several times in JSfiddle and it works fine there. When I run my page locally `.dropDown` does not animate down and does not `.slideUp` when other `li` elements are clicked. Here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqNMX/) and my HTML head as well so you can see what I'm calling.

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">

<title>Nav test</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="nav.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="nav.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
</head>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the rest of your markup?!

Comment: Use firebug to find the error or check browser console.

Comment: Include jQuery before jQuery UI

Comment: Also, you probably want to make up your mind about what charset you're telling the browser you're using. (You've used by the old-style `meta` tag and the new-style one, but they declare different charsets! UTF-8 != ISO-8859-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI builds on top of jQuery, adding to the functions and objects defined by jQuery. So you have to include the jQuery UI script **after** the jQuery script.

Not:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

but rather:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><!-- First jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>   <!-- THEN jQuery UI -->
```

With the scripts in the order you've included them, in the JavaScript console you should be seeing an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

(The exact text will vary from browser to browser.)

Comment: WOW, Thank you so much. never would have gotten that; now I know!

Comment: @LetteredFox: You're welcome! Glad that helped. It's well-worth getting used to looking in the JavaScript console (all browsers have one). That's really the first place to look when things aren't working. :-) Best,